# How to convert between PGP keyrings and Java keystore files?

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, pgp

I am currently working on an Android app that talks to a server process on a remote machine. The installation packages for both the Android client and server need to be cryptographically signed; the Android client with a Java Keystore File (JKS) and the server with a PGP key from a keyring file. If possible, I would like to reduce the dependencies by signing both packages with the same key, but neither signing tool supports the opposite file format.

Is it possible to convert a PGP keyring file into a JKS file? Or alternatively, is it possible to convert a JKS file into a PGP keyring file? If so, how?

Edit for clarification: The idea here is to use a single cryptographic key as input for two different signing tools. The tools do not know about each other; it's just some random key to them. I do not want to sign an Android package with PGP, or the server installation package with Android's signing tool, as either would make the output unreadable to the end user.

Comment: But just having the (let's assume: RSA) keys in the other format wouldn't be you want though. I assume you want also generate a PGP signature with a JKS key or a Android signature with a PGP key. They don't actually use the same structure, do they?

Comment: Well, the file formats are obviously different, but the basic algorithm used to sign the content should be the same with either PGP or Android signatures. Or that's my understanding anyway.

Comment: Even if they use (or support) the same signature scheme (e.g. RSA with the probabilistic signature scheme with the same hash) how would that help you if still cannot generate a readable file for one application with the other? I understand that it seems like a neat idea, but in practice building such a cross system solution does not seem to be worth the effort instead just using two (incompatible) keys.

Comment: I don't think we're understanding each other correctly. Edited the original question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it might be theoretically possible there are certainly no tools to do that. If you would want to write one yourself there are a lot of hurdles to overcome. On a low level view there are many different ways to sign data (even if you restrict yourself to RSA, there are still many standards and parameters to choose from). On a high level view such key files and their front end abstractions of certificates or simply "keys" on the pgp side contain a lot meta information like a validity period, ownership information and so on. If you could actually deal with the low crypto problems then you still have to define some translation from one set of meta data to the other.

Also from a cryptographic point of view any key reuse is strongly frowned upon. There are many ways typically sound primitives can break apart if they are used in an unintended way. Certainly the authors and implementers of the algorithms behind the Android tools and the PGP tools did not imagine their tools to be used with such cross generated keys.